# Memory problem with PowerBuilder 11.5 and C# COM component

Tags: c#, com-interop, powerbuilder

First of all, sorry for my english.

I'm developing a COM component in C# (which implements IDisposable) to use it from PowerBuilder something like this:

```
OLEObject lole_comComponent

lole_comComponent = Create OLEObject
lole_comComponent.ConnectToNewObject("MyComComponent")

[Do some stuff...]

lole_component.DisconnectObject()
destroy lole_component
GarbageCollect()
```

With this code, destructor of COM Component is triggered when close de app. I've added a method to the component that calls a private Dispose method. Something like this:

```
OLEObject lole_comComponent

lole_comComponent = Create OLEObject
lole_comComponent.ConnectToNewObject("MyComComponent")

[Do some stuff...]

lole_component.Close()  // this method calls Dispose(true)
lole_component.DisconnectObject()
destroy lole_component

GarbageCollect()
```

In neither of the two examples the memory used by the component is released.

How I can free the memory used by the COM component?

I'm using PowerBuilder 11.5.1 Build 4740.

Comment: Could you post the code of your C# class' `.Dispose()` method?

Comment: @David It's something like that http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.80).aspx#Y480

Comment: Are you doing anything like `lole_thing = lole_component.SomeThing`? If so you need to disconnect and destroy `lole_thing` as well.

Comment: @Hugh - good catch, looking at the code there are two different OLEObject variables being referenced.  Of course, it could also just be a type.

Comment: @Hugh @HillBilly It's a mistake. lole_comComponent and lole_component are the same variable. I've assingned variables in two ways: 1: lole_thing = lole_com.Property... lole_thing.DisconnectObject() and destroy lole_thing. 2: lole_thing.SetAutomationPointer(lole_com.Property) and diconnect and destroy at the end of process.

Answer (score 1):

I'll confess to being fuzzy on who is owning the memory in this situation, PowerBuilder or the control, but one fact that may be helpful (or not) is the fact that PowerBuilder tends to hang on to memory it gets allocated from the OS. The theory is that memory requests are performance expensive operations, so instead of going through cycles of requesting and releasing memory (PB doesn't know what you're going to do next), it just hangs onto memory it has requested and doesn't need right now.

HTH,

Terry.

Comment: I understand.

My PB app runs as Windows service and receives requests to perform actions and one of this actions require COM component.

If I can't release certain objects (in this case, the OLEObjects affected by the COM component other than it does ConnectToNewObject) makes the memory of my service will increase until crashes, usually memory problems. 

One more thing... COM component is simple, I think that is not so complicated as to require an advanced memory management. Still, all implements IDisposable to release properly.

Comment: So, just to be clear, when PowerBuilder hangs on to memory, it *will* reuse it. The second time your COM object is called, PB could reuse the memory allocated the first time, assuming it's not already used by something else. Unless there's a memory leak, this characteristic of PB I've described won't make you run out of memory.

Comment: It gives the impression that memory is not reused, because every time COM component is called, memory grows, aprox. 150-300K

Comment: @Merrin: Definitely a bug, but like I said, I haven't got the background to suggest that it's definitely PB or definitely the COM object; I don't know who "owns" that memory that is being lost. Everything I've suggested may be a complete red herring.